# Cannot pass variables between javascript function and ajax in django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

This is a proper noob question it would seem, so apologies, but I can't seem to solve it so I'm reaching out for some assistance.

I have a function in my .js file that interacts with the Google Places library to autocomplete a field in a form. I then have an ajax function that runs when you click the submit button which creates variables in the django session. The data of interest to me is `lat` and `long`.

However, for some reason, I can't seem to get the data to pass from one to the other. I know the ajax function is working because if I type in fixed values they propagate through to django, but I can't seem to get it to update dynamically.

```
const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken');
var lat;
var lng;

function autocomplete_location() {
    let defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.6331, -11.7247),
        new google.maps.LatLng(59.4850, 1.5906));

    let input = document.getElementById('id_your_location');
    let options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ["address"],
        fields: ["name", "geometry"],
    };

    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

        // Get place info
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        // Do whatever with the value!
        lat = place.geometry.location.lat()
        lng = place.geometry.location.lng()

        console.log(lat)
        console.log(lng)
    })
}


$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".btn").click(function (){
        $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
                    'lat': lat,
                    'long': lng,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    window.location.replace('/new_path/')
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)

                }
        })
    })
})
```

UPDATE -----------------------------------------------------------

I have managed to get this working. I have moved the ajax call into the autocomplete function, but it only works when I click the submit button, it does not work when I press the enter key, so I need to brush up on my JS and ajax to solve that problem.

```
const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken');

function autocomplete_location() {
    let defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.6331, -11.7247),
        new google.maps.LatLng(59.4850, 1.5906));

    let input = document.getElementById('id_your_location');
    let options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ["address"],
        fields: ["name", "geometry"],
    };

    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

        // Get place info
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        // Do whatever with the value!
        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

        console.log(lat)
        console.log(lng)

        $("form").submit(function (){
            $.ajax({
                    url: '',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
                        'lat': lat,
                        'long': lng,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        // this is not good. But I couldn't find a better way to redirect
                        // window.location.replace('/coach/')
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error)

                    }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

where do you call `autocomplete_location()` ? try passing lat and long in that function as parameters e.g. `autocomplete_location(lat, long)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added this but it hasn't made a difference. As for when in it called, it is loaded in the head of the html.

<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=autocomplete_location&libraries=places" defer></script>
</head>